# Is there a way to give table level access with a condition in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-iam

I'm trying to give people temporary access to a specific table in BigQuery but not finding a way to do it, the UI for giving access to a table doesn't have the condition part in it as for the IAM page on GCP.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: does this answer your question? [IAM Temporary Access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-temporary-access#temporary)

Comment: no, this is for the IAM page on GCP, exactly the feature I'm missing from the view when giving access to a specific BigQuery table.